# In rust, what's the idiomatic way of expressing a struct that can be ordered, but only in reference to a standard value?

Tags: sorting, rust, data-structures

I'm trying to implement a game similar to [GeoGuessr](https://www.geoguessr.com/), where players enter geographic coordinates according to a street-view image, and are ranked by their distance to the correct location of the image.

I need a data structure to represent the submission of a player, and I want it to implement `PartialEq` and `PartialOrd` so that it can be easily sorted within container structures. However, unlike ordinary `PartialOrd` structures that are comparable by themselves, my structure is only comparable in reference to *the correct answer*.

- I would like the rankings to be accessible at any time, so I'd prefer a container that always maintains the order of its elements to avoid the sorting costs, in my case I chose [skiplist::ordered_skiplist::OrderedSkipList](https://docs.rs/skiplist/latest/skiplist/ordered_skiplist/struct.OrderedSkipList.html). That means methods like `sort_by_key` are unavailable to me, and I have to implement `PartialOrd` for my structure.

So I ended up keeping a reference to the correct answer as a field in my structure:

```rust
struct Submission<'a> {
    submitted: Location,
    correct: &'a Location,
}

impl Submission<'_> {
    fn distance(&self) -> f64 {
        self.submitted.distance(*self.correct)
    }
}

impl PartialEq for Submission<'_> {
    fn eq(&self, other: &Self) -> bool {
        let d1 = self.distance();
        let d2 = other.distance();
        d1.eq(&d2)
    }
}

impl PartialOrd for Submission<'_> {
    fn partial_cmp(&self, other: &Self) -> Option<std::cmp::Ordering> {
        let d1 = self.distance();
        let d2 = other.distance();
        d1.partial_cmp(&d2)
    }
}
```

But this doesn't seem idiomatic to me, as it doesn't restrict comparison between `Submission`s with different `correct` references, which would be invalid. Also, maintaining the same `correct` reference in each `Submission` seems a redundant cost. Is there a more idiomatic way of defining the data structure for this scenario?

**Edit:**

I've considered comparing the `correct` references in `partial_cmp` and returning `None` for invalid comparisons, but that's also redundant for my case as I can prevent this in coding myself. I'm looking for a compile-time way of preventing invalid comparisons, rather than a runtime one.

Comment: Why do you need `PartialOrd`? For `BTreeMap`?

Comment: 'so that it can be easily sorted within container structures' - bear in mind that there are other methods on the container types for sorting (e.g. `sort_by_key`) that take closures, and so might be more useful here.

Comment: Your implementation of `partial_cmp` should check if `self` and `other` contain the same `correct`. If not, return `None`.

Comment: @JoeClay I think not all container structures support such methods, e.g. the structures that always keep the elements sorted, like `BTreeMap` mentioned by @ChayimFriedman , which require the elements to implement `PartialOrd` or `Ord` themselves for sorting. What I intended to use was [skiplist::ordered_skiplist::OrderedSkipList](https://docs.rs/skiplist/latest/skiplist/ordered_skiplist/struct.OrderedSkipList.html) or please suggest if there are better alternatives

Comment: If you need `Ord` (for `BTreeMap` for instance) and not just `PartialOrd`, then you should state that outright in your question.

Comment: If your question is just "is there something more idiomatic to do?", with the information we have, I'd say no. Apparently, in your situation, there is *not* a total order on the submissions anyways (what if two submissions are *exactly* at the same distance?) so it seems ok to encode it implementing only `PartialOrd`, and not `Ord`. And, as said by @PitaJ, if you don't want submissions with difference `correct` field to be comparable, just compare `correct` before, and return `None` if they differ. I have the impression that there is a quite easy 1-1 mapping between Rust code and what you want

Comment: I recently published [copse](https://crates.io/crates/copse), which provides a `BTreeMap` that sorts according to a comparator (that can have runtime-dynamic state) rather than the `Ord` trait.   Thus you could create such a `BTreeMap` for your solution (declared with a comparator that orders submissions according to that solution), then simply add each submission to it.